# Iterate properties of an object knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, knockout-2.0

From what I've been able to find online I don't think it's possible to use the foreach data-bind to iterate through the properties of an observable object in knockout at this time.

If someone could help me with a solution to what I'm trying to do I'd be very thankful.

Let's say I have an array of movies objects:

```
var movies = [{
    title: 'My First Movie',
    genre: 'comedy',
    year: '1984'    
},
{
    title: 'My Next Movie',
    genre: 'horror',
    year: '1988'
},
];
```

And what I would like to do is display this data in a table, but a different table for each genre of movie.

So I attempted something like this:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: movieGenre">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td data-bind="year"></td>
            <td data-bind="title"></td>
            <td data-bind="genre"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

and my data source changed to look like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < movies.length; ++i) {
    if (typeof moviesGenres[movies.genre] === 'undefined')
        moviesGenres[movies.genre] = [];
    moviesGenres[movies.genre].push(movie);
}
```

I've tried about a dozen other solutions, and I'm starting to wonder if it's my lack of knowledge of knockout(I'm pretty green on it still), or it's just not possible the way I'd like it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make your array "movies" an KO observable array and the array "movieGenre" a KO computed property. Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/omegasilva/GXNCs/11/).

The code in the fiddle is given below for reader convenience;

KO View Model

```
function MoviesViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.movies = ko.observableArray([
        {
            title: 'My First Movie',
            genre: 'comedy',
            year: '1984'
        },
        {
            title: 'My Next Movie',
            genre: 'horror',
            year: '1988'
        },
        {
            title: 'My Other Movie',
            genre: 'horror',
            year: '1986'
        }
    ]);

    self.movieGenre = ko.computed(function() {
        var genres = new Array();

        var moviesArray = self.movies();
        for (var i = 0; i < moviesArray.length; i++) {
            if (genres.indexOf(moviesArray[i].genre) < 0) {
                genres.push(moviesArray[i].genre);
            }
        }

        return genres;
    });  
};
```

HTML

```
<div data-bind="foreach: movieGenre()">
    <h3 data-bind="text: 'Genere : ' + $data"></h3>
    <table border="solid">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Genre</th>
                <th>Year</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody data-bind="foreach: $parent.movies">
            <!-- ko if: $data.genre === $parent -->
            <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: $data.title"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: $data.genre"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: $data.year"></td>
            </tr>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

As you can see "movieGenre" is made a computed property. Whenever the observable array "movies" changes, the moveGenre is calculated and cached. However, since this is not declared as a writable computed property, you cannot bind this to your view. Hence, it's value is used in the data binding.

The approach for rendering is simply looping through the calculated "movieGenre", and nest another loop for movies. Before adding a row to the table, for the corresponding table, the movie object is evaluated with the current movieGenre. Here, the *container-less control flow syntax* is used. We can use the "if" binding, but that would leave an empty table row per each movie object where the genre is otherwise.

The $parent binding context is used to access the parent contexts in the nested loop.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. This is pretty much what I ended up doing, forgot to update my question when I figured it out.